# Can Tab Bar view be used only in the second screen application?

Tags: ios, hig

I am just starting out iOS development and have some doubts about Tab Bars Human Interface Guidelines provided by Apple.

On the iOS HIG document concerning Tab Bars, it reads:

> "A tab bar appears at the bottom edge of the screen and should be
>   accessible from **every location** in the app."

The app I am developing and would like to see published in the App Store once finished, would have a ListView as it's first screen that would then go to another screen with a tabbed interface after an item being selected. It would also be possible to go back to the first screen (the one with the list) at any time within the tabbed interface (the 2nd screen).

So, my question is if it's ok to have a Tab Bar interface only in the second screen of an iOS application or would something like that might result in some restrictions by apple approving?

Thanks.

Comment: yes, you can have tab bar in second screen. I have such apps. first screen as language select screen and second screen with tab bar controller

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please consider making it into an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: posted answer with more details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is **YES**.

Yes, you can have tab bar in second screen.  Consider the app where you have first screen as language select screen and second screen with tab bar controller.

With statement below, what Apple means is once you are in tab-bar controller **and tab-bar controller is in scope**, tab-bar controller should be accessible. You can hide the tab-bar, but on tapping, it should come again at the bottom of screen.

"A tab bar appears at the bottom edge of the screen and should be accessible from every location in the app."

Answer (score 1):

Main words -> **Should be**. Apple wants you to make your apps in the most intuitive and user friendly way possible. Many standard apps use this paradigm (ie App Store Application) so they know iOS users are accustomed as to how to navigate. However, Apple themselves even make exceptions to this rule (ie. Playing a song inside the Music App). But yeah, they'll let you do it no problem.